# CSS min-height not resizing based on content

Tags: html, css, checkbox, height, show

I am currently trying to make content appear when a label is selected. The issue which I am having is that the content which will appear will vary in size based on the data which is being pulled in so I cannot set a specific height which will work in all cases. I thought the best way to work around this was to use min-height but the height doesn't seem to be betting itself based on the length of the size of the content. How can I fix this o that the size will be based on how much content there is.

```css
#block {
  background: yellow;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: height 300ms linear;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showContent {
  display: none;
}

#showContent:checked+#block {
  min-height: 5px;
}

#showContent:not(:checked) {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label for="showContent">Show content</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="showContent" />
<div id="block">
  Show content ..... Bla bla bla
</div>
```

jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sacora9/81m14v1s/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the height to `auto`. Otherwise, you set `min-height:5px`, but the height is still set to `0`, so the calculated height will be `5px`. So the solution is to release the `height` and make it free :

```css
#block {
  background: yellow;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: height 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: height 300ms linear;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showContent {
  display: none;
}

#showContent:checked+#block {
  height : auto; /* <----- Here, instead of min-height: 5px */
}

#showContent:not(:checked) {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label for="showContent">Show content</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="showContent" />
<div id="block">
  Show content ..... Bla bla bla
</div>
```

EDIT

I've just noticed the animation part. Transition from 0 to auto is tricky, but here's the trick :

```css
#block {
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showContent {
  display: none;
}

#showContent:checked+#block {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0);
}

#showContent:not(:checked) {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label for="showContent">Show content</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="showContent" />
<div id="block">
  Show content ..... Bla bla bla
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your example, `block` still has `height: 0;` applied to it even when `showContent` is checked. Instead, set the height to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this while maintaining the animation would be to use max-height instead:

```
#block {
  background: yellow;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: max-height 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: max-height 300ms linear;
  transition: max-height 300ms linear;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showContent {
  display: none; 
}
#showContent:checked + #block {
  max-height: 100px; /*any value larger than the content */
}
#showContent:not(:checked){
  height:0px;
}
```